# java how do I get the latest tweet for a particular user

Tags: java, twitter, twitter4j

I would like to get latest tweet from @Citi in java. I thought I should use twitter4j (BUT anything easier would be fine). I cannot tell from the documentation how to supply the "user" i.e. @Citi?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Twitter twitter = new TwitterFactory().getInstance();
    List<Status> statusList = null;
    try {
        statusList = twitter.getUserTimeline("@Citi");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    for (Status status : statusList) {
                    System.out.println(status.toString());
           }        
}
```

I tried the above but it crashes on getUserTimeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code must create an instance of `ConfigurationBuider` and pass in your Twitter API credentials. Add the following.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    ConfigurationBuilder cb = new ConfigurationBuilder();

    cb.setDebugEnabled(true)
      .setOAuthConsumerKey("Your Cosumer Key")
      .setOAuthConsumerSecret("Your Consumer Secret")
      .setOAuthAccessToken("Your Access Token")
      .setOAuthAccessTokenSecret("Your Access Token Secret");
    TwitterFactory tf = new TwitterFactory(cb.build());

    Twitter twitter = tf.getInstance();

    List<Status> statusList = null;

   try {
        statusList = twitter.getUserTimeline("@Citi");
    } catch (TwitterException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    for (Status status : statusList) {
        System.out.println(status.toString());
    }        
}
```

A Twitter API account is required to use the Twitter API.  Twitter requires this so they can track who is using their API and conduct activities such as rate limiting.  To obtain a Twitter API account, first create a Twitter account, then create the API account at this page: https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: I don't understand. Why do I need to twitter API credentials? It is a public page. I don't have a twitter account and I can see it...

Comment: @ManInMoon To use the twitter api you need an API account with credentials, basically they want to know who is accessing their api so they can perform things like rate limiting.  To get a twitter api account, first create a twitter account then create an api account here: https://dev.twitter.com/

Comment: Ah OK. Thank you for explaining. SO might be easier to just grab webpage content

Comment: @ManInMoon It could be, but if the UI changes you may be out of luck.  The API would be the appropriate way to access the data.  Its not too painful to setup those accounts and provide the credentials.

Answer (score 0):

have you looked into the provided examples?
http://twitter4j.org/en/code-examples.html

You need to have OAuth credentials configured in your twitter4j.properties
See: http://twitter4j.org/en/configuration.html

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Create application in developer and you'll get consumer keys for the application. These are application specific keys to identify your application. Then you'll have to supply access tokens, which are user specific keys. With the combination of these four, Any application with any user given, you can get its tweets. If you want to get tweets in real time, user Streaming API, otherwise you can get last 20 Tweets with the code you posted.